# detect DHCP server on a wired network

Tags: windows-7, dhcp-server

On Windows 7, how can I check if there is a DHCP server ruling the LAN on which my computer is running ? How to detect its IP address ?

Comment: Technically, you’d implement half a DHCP client: Send `DHCPDISCOVER`, listen for `DHCPOFFER`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite simply:

You can tell that there is a DHCP server on your network by testing your NIC configuration and seeing if it is set for DHCP, and if it is, if you've pulled an IP address.

You can kill that bird, and the other(what is the address of the server?) with one stone, simply by going to a command line and using "ipconfig /all". Look for an entry that says "DHCP Server. . . . . .:" and it will tell you the address of the DHCP server.

Now, if you're trying to determine if your DHCP server is actually a server or a router, you'd need to discuss that with an admin.

Comment: You can probably tell if the DHCP server is a router if the default route IP is the same IP as the DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

If your client computer is configured to get its address using DHCP, then `ipconfig /all` command will show you which server supplied its address.

If, however, your client is using a static IP address, this information will not be shown.  You can use the `DHCPLOC` [TechNet / resource kit tool](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DHCPLOC-Utility-34262d82) is a more informative solution, detecting DHCP servers - even ones that you aren't expecting.  It will show you the whole offer process.  It does not lend itself well to being a scriptable tool, since it is designed to be run interactively, but it will deliver the information.